# Sorting algorithm that learns the order of elements?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I was wondering if there is a name for an algorithm that learns the order of a set of elements based on sorted lists of these elements and then is able to sort lists consisting of some of these elements using that order.

Example:

We have 5 elements: "tiny", "small", "medium", "large", "huge". The algorithm doesn't understand the meaning of these words, of course. We can form lists with some of these words in it which are sorted by the "size" of the word (from smallest to largest):

- "small", "medium", "huge"
- "tiny", "medium", "large"
- "tiny", "small", "large", "huge"

The algorithm I search takes only these sorted lists and forms a single list with all the words, correctly sorted (that would be ["tiny", "small", "medium", "large", "huge"]).

Comment: Which language you prefer?

Comment: Java, but actually I just wanted to know if there is a name for that algorithm. I don't need actual code

Comment: You can use hashmap that would be easy to implement

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Maybe you could post this as a full answer?

Comment: How can I use HashMap to detect the correct order of strings?

Comment: t probably a learning algorithm. IF fed the 1st list is has firm believes as to which ordering is ok, If fed the 2nd list it has some uncertainty - no believes in how to arrange tiny/small and large/huge but aware that tiny and small are both "less" then medium & large and huge are both "more" then medium. The 3rd list alleviates this uncertainty to correct believes for all of them. You could model it with a tree structure that has lists as nodes - if > 1 item in node-list, there is uncertainty. on new data you reorder/add to leaves. left hand is smaller, right handis bigger

Comment: @AndrewWatson Hashmaps is another way - you could use approxed values of 1000 for the first 3 inputs (1000,2000,3000) and on further input put stuff in between until all input are there. IF uncertainty arises, choose same numeric values for these inputs and modify them if new data arises

Comment: Yeah I agree with you but using hashmap would be easier to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build up a directed graph from the examples where the words are the vertices and with edges reflecting the sequence. E.g. the first example would give edges from "small" to "medium" and from "medium" to "huge".

Then do a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the graph.

Answer (score 2):

Use any kind of sort algorithm, a sorting algorithm need an input so that if you compare two elements, you will know which element comes first.

For example:

```
array.sort(compareFunction)
```

Where `compareFunction` take 2 elements and return if the first element comes first in the list than the second element.

From the list of your short lists, you need to figure out which come first for every two elements.

Use your input lists, build a table like this:

```
       tiny small medium huge large
tiny    -    T       T     T    T
small   F    -       T     T    T
medium  F    F       -     T    T
huge    F    F       F     -    T
large   F    F       F     F    -
```

Where `table[i][j]` is true if `i < j`.

Then use that table to solve your compareFunction.